# Postgresql jsonb enum mapping

Tags: .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

**Postgresql writes index value when mapping enum to jsonb fields. How can I replace it with enum value?**

By default, any enum properties in your model will be mapped to database integers. EF Core 2.1 also allows you to map these to strings in the database with value converters.

However, the Npgsql provider also allows you to map your CLR enums to database enum types. This option, unique to PostgreSQL, provides the best of both worlds: the enum is internally stored in the database as a number (minimal storage), but is handled like a string (more usable, no need to remember numeric values) and has type safety.

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="6.0.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Design" Version="1.1.0" />
```

```cs
public class Company : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "jsonb")]
    public CompanyJsonData Json { get; set; }

    public RowStatus Status { get; set; } //this work
}

public class CompanyJsonData
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public RowStatus Status { get; set; } //this does not work
}

// Program.cs
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<RowStatus>();
// :DbContext OnModelCreating method
modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<RowStatus>();

public enum RowStatus
{
    active = 1,

    passive = 2,

    deleted = 3
}
```

Current:

```json
{
  "RowStatus": 3
}
```

Must be:

```json
{
  "RowStatus": "deleted"
}
```

Comment: Postgresql  does not do this. Can you provide details pls.

Comment: i added all of code parts for you

Comment: I think that you need to use Enun.ToString and Enum.TryParse in the getter/setter of CompanyJsonData.Status

Answer (score 1):

you should add dbcontext

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasPostgresEnum<RowStatus>();
}
```

at program.cs

```cs
NpgsqlConnection.GlobalTypeMapper.MapEnum<RowStatus>();
```

after that add and apply migration

documentation here
https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1

Answer (score 0):

.net 7+ version

```cs
// Call UseNodaTime() when building your data source:
var dataSourceBuilder = new NpgsqlDataSourceBuilder(/* connection string */);
dataSourceBuilder.MapEnum<Mood>();
var dataSource = dataSourceBuilder.Build();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(dataSource));
```